# HOW to convert List<File> into List<Asset> in flutter

Tags: ios, list, flutter, assets, imagepicker

I am using multiple image picker to get mutliple images from gallery and it return a list of Asset,
and i have successfully converted that image to list of files as List by using path from asset.

```
resultList = await MultiImagePicker.pickImages(
    maxImages: 5,
    enableCamera: false,
  );
```

file.add(asset.identifier);

```
var path = await FlutterAbsolutePath.getAbsolutePath(resultList[i].identifier);
                _pathofimages.add(File(path));
```

but not i need to edit that again as i have implemented crop feature as well...
so in that case i need to reverse the process

like
adding asset in List using filepath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a converter function.
Would you try using this?

uuid: ^2.1.0

```
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

...

  Future<Asset> fileToAsset(File image) async {
    String fileName = basename(image.path);
    var decodedImage = await decodeImageFromList(image.readAsBytesSync());
    return Asset(uuid.v4(), fileName, decodedImage.width, decodedImage.height);
  }
```

Comment: Does this Asset get save to local disk? when I resume the application next time, will I be able to retrieve this Asset again?